# Table of Figures

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

Is there a nice way to include multiple figures in the format of a table?

I want it to look something like the following mock-up (pardon my terrible MS Paint skills), and am willing to `include` any necessary packages.  I would love it if there were a nice way to label the columns as rows as I did (`a` and `b`, and `1`, `2`, and `3`).

[image]

Comment: Will this be part of a bigger `figure` or `table`? And how do you want to be able to reference the figures? For example, `\ref{figurea1}` should return `1a1` if it's part of `Figure 1`?

Comment: @Werner This is not part of a bigger table--I want a table made up of these 6 figures.  I want to `include` each of them as a separate figure, and be able to `\ref` them separately as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works by defining a new `\fixedlabel` labelling scheme. `\fixedlabel{<lab>}{<tag>}` fixes the label `<tag>` associated with `<lab>` (similar to the `\tag` labelling mechanism of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

[image]

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52189/including-table-of-figures
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\fixedlabel#1#2{%
  \@bsphack%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}cc}
    & a & b \\
    1 & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block1a}{1a} 
      & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block1b}{1b} \\ \\
    2 & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block2a}{2a} 
      & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block2b}{2b} \\ \\
    3 & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block3a}{3a} 
      & \rule[-25pt]{100pt}{50pt}\fixedlabel{block3b}{3b}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is a caption.}\label{figtab}
\end{table}

See, for example, \ref{block1a} and~\ref{block2b} in Table~\ref{figtab}.

\end{document}
```

A [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-compatible version of `\fixedlabel` is given by:

```
\def\fixedlabel#1#2{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@currentlabelname
    \edef\@currentlabelname{%
      \expandafter\strip@period\@currentlabelname\relax.\relax\@@@%
    }%
    \phantomsection%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#1}{%
        {#2}%
        {\thepage}%
        {#2}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
```

Comment: I have a slight problem.  In my document the label for each row is not simply `1`, `2`, `3`--rather, it is some longer text such as `\text{$p = 0.1\%$ noise, $N = 100$ trials}`.  This text is too long, as it pushes both figures to its right into the margin.  How can I make this labeling text separate into two lines?  When I try `\text{$p = 0.1\%$ noise,} \\ \text{$N = 100$ trials}` the second line gets pushed all the way beneath the figure...

Comment: @jamaicanworm: You could insert a `tabular` for those entries: `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} $p = 0.1\%$ noise, \\ $N = 100$ trials \end{tabular}` The zero-padding ensures that your original columnar spacing (isn't affected, but allows for you to add multiple rows within a single cell.

Comment: Thanks, but then the label gets pushed to the bottom of the row, instead of remaining vertically centered in the row.

Comment: @jamaicanworm: How about using an `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5em}` column type for the left column (*not* for the inner `tabular`, but the *outer* `tabular`). This would require the addition of the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). My MWE uses `\rule` for a fake image, so I didn't have time to play around. Give some feedback if you're still stuck and I'll post an updated MWE.

Comment: @Wenrer Great!  This might be a separate question, but now the following issue has come up--one of the figures I am including is too large--is there a way to automatically resize it so that it takes up the same amount of space as the other figures in the table?

Comment: @jamaicanworm: If all the figures except one is of an inappropriate size, you can store one of the OK ones in a box (to measure it's width) and then resize the non-OK one to that width. Something like `\newsavebox{\myfig}\savebox{\myfig}{\includegraphics[..]{OK-fig}}` and then use `\includegraphics[width=\wd\myfig]{non-OK-fig}`. If this is not clear, ask a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764).

Answer (score 7):

Here's one possible solution using the [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\newcounter{tmp}

% \MyIm{<figure name>}{<label>}
\newcommand\MyIm[2]{%
  \captionof*{subfigure}{}
  \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=2cm]{#1}
  \captionof{subfigure}{}\label{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcounter{tmp}{\thefigure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{tabu}{>{\refstepcounter{figure}\thefigure\setcounter{subfigure}{0}}l%
  X[c,m]X[c,m]}
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\setcounter{figure}{0}} & a & b \\[-20pt]
  & \MyIm{name1}{a} & \MyIm{name2}{b}  \\[-30pt]
  & \MyIm{name3}{c} & \MyIm{name4}{d}  \\[-30pt]
  & \MyIm{name5}{e} & \MyIm{name6}{f} 
\end{tabu}\setcounter{figure}{\thetmp} 
\end{center}

\ref{a} \ref{b} \ref{c} \ref{d} \ref{e} \ref{f}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks:

1. A `tmp` counter was used to store the value of the counter `figure` before the table and then, at the end the value for `figure` was restored
2. The [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcapton) package was used to provide an empty caption for each figure; this allows the easy assignment of a `\label` for cross-referencing.
3. This solution cooperates with `hyperref`; the only thing to do is to load `hyperref` and `hypcap`:

   ```
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{hypcap}
   ```